# Background color is changing and undoing again in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I am trying to change background colour of body (background color changer project)using jquery, it changes and again comes to default background-color.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Background-Color Changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="">
        <h3>Change the Background-Color (Hex code only)</h3>
        <input type="text" name="" id="name" maxlength="7" placeholder="#" />
        <button id="btn1" type="submit">Change</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $('body').css("background-color", $("#name").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `type="submit"` attribute of change button. Your page is getting refresh  everytime you click the button as explained in answer by @blex

Answer (score 0):

Your button is inside a `form`, so when you click it, the form is submitted, and the page is reloaded. To prevent the form from being submitted, you can do this:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function (evt) { // <- the event
    $('body').css("background-color", $("#name").val());
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior for that event
});
```

[More info on `Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: By changing button type to 'button' the problem was solved. Thanks for explanation.